# How do I allow an MIME extension map in ASP.NET vNext?

Tags: configuration, permissions, mime-types, asp.net-core

### Background

I have a piece of LESS code that needs to be compiled at runtime with Less.js -- it calculates some things via JavaScript -- so I can't use the task runner, etc.

In my index.html, I have:

```
<head>
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="assets/less/DynamicHeight.less" />
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/less/less.js"></script>
   ... 
</head>
```

### Problem

Less.js appears unable to find the file:

[image: LESS.js barfing because IIS can't serve the file]

And when I try to access the file directly, I see:

[image]

### Question

How can I add the configuration that will allow this less file to be downloaded? Am I still able to use `web.config` files with vNext, or do I need to do something with `config.json` instead?

### Lead 1: Should I use Owin?

Thinking this might be the right path but I'm pretty unfamiliar.

I see a number of tutorials out there, such as [K. Scott Allen's](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx), which reference code such as:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var options = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider()
        };
        ((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)options.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings.Add(
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(".less", "text/css"));
        app.UseStaticFiles(options);
    }
```

However, it appears that in its current version, asp.net is looking for a signature of `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` instead.

The `IApplicationBuilder` class doesn't have a method along the lines of `UseStaticFiles` -- it only has a signature of `IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)`.

I have a feeling that this is likely the right path to solve the issue -- I just can't find out how to propertly configure the `IAppliationBuilder` to map the MIME extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I believe I figured it out.

### Step 1: Add the appropriate library for static files

In ASP.NET vNext, this is `Microsoft.Aspnet.StaticFiles`.

In your `project.json` file, add the following under `"dependencies"`:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta2"
```

This adds the static middleware method that you can use later.

### Step 2: Configure the app to use Static Files

Add the using statement at the top:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles;
```

At this point, the `app.UseStaticFiles` method will be available, so your `Configure` method can look as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var options = new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider()
    };
    ((FileExtensionContentTypeProvider)options.ContentTypeProvider).Mappings.Add(
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(".less", "text/css"));
    app.UseStaticFiles(options);
}
```

And voila! I get text when browsing to .less files, and no more error is appearing from LessJS.

Comment: Worked well for getting SVG going on azure websites; checked for `ContainsKey` and replaced value if found, else `Add` (however unnecessary that may have been)

Comment: @bdimag glad it helped! Be aware that vNext is still changing, so this approach may not always make sense if they change it in the future.

Answer (score 5):

In .NET Core 1.0.1, SeanKileen answer is still good. The following is a simple code rewrite:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ...)

    var contentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    contentTypeProvider.Mappings[".map"] = "application/javascript";
    contentTypeProvider.Mappings[".less"] = "text/css";

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider
    });
```

The above code EXTENDS the default mapping list [(see the source)](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/b49b46c5b63cf4db7285500470aed8ac0eea93db/src/Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs), which already has ~370 mappings.

Avoid using the `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` constructor overload that takes a dictionary (as suggested by JHo) if you want those 370 default mappings.

Answer (score -1):

SeanKilleen's answer is right on, and still works ASP.NET Core RC1.  My only improvement is to write the exact same code using collection initializers to make it cleaner.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { ".less", "text/css" },
        { ".babylon", "text/json" },
        // ....
    })
});
```

Comment: This code actually does not generates the same result. You are using a different class constructor and that means your mapping list will be empty plus the explicit mappings. SeanKilleen answer uses the default constructor which has hundreds of default mappings. The result is very different. See the source [code here](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/b49b46c5b63cf4db7285500470aed8ac0eea93db/src/Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs)